# getting incorrect image url when sending it in email from my own domain

Tags: php, email, kohana

I have an issue with sending email with image. I am using rich text editor. The point is when I put the image URL from another domain, it is correct and  I'm getting email correctly with that image. But when I am trying to pass the URL of an image from my own domain, instead of getting for example

> img src = "my_domain_name.ru/path_to_image"

I am getting this in email message

> img src = "../../../path_to_image"

I am not getting domain_name in url .
I am codding on Php Kohana framework.
Please help, if there is any idea

Comment: It might be possible to set this in the Rich Text Editor, depending on which product you are using

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  ' to set this'

Comment: CKEditor has a configuration option, for example: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.baseHref

Comment: Thanks, but i think the problem somewhere in my .htaccess, whih not allow the access to my domain images, becouse the other images which i am getting from another servers, everythink is ok

Comment: no - your server's images will be stored as relative paths because they're on the same server. IIRC it's the default behaviour of rich text editors and the big products have taken steps to turn it off (like CKEditor with that setting)

Comment: Well i don't know what exactly do, i am using TinyMCE text editor product

Comment: There should be a setting for that. It should be something like "relative paths in images", that would be worth Googling around

Comment: look i have turned off relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : true,
document_base_url : "/",
convert_urls : true,    but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
            fix_content_duplication: true,
            content_css : "/adresseofyourcss.css",
            remove_script_host : false,
            relative_urls : true,
            urlconvertor_callback: "convLinkVC",
            theme : "advanced",
            document_base_url : "http://www.yourbaseaddress.com/"
        });

        function convLinkVC(strUrl, node, on_save) {
            strUrl=strUrl.replace("http://www.yourbaseaddress.com","");
            return strUrl;
        }
    </script>
```

THIS IS WORKING NOW

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has a `relative_urls` setting that you need to set to `false`.

See e.g. [this forum thread](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1881)

Here's the [official TinyMCE page on the issue with examples](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/url_conversion.php)

Comment: relative_urls : false  No result, i have changed that everywhere it possible, even have changed the document_base_url